# Populate object from CSV

Tags: java

This program has a class called **group** which stores an array of data of another object **(student)**, i'm trying to read student information from a CSV and use the **addNewStudent** method to add the student a group. I have been trying using both the BufferedReader and Scanner however i'm still getting an exception.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

Below is my code attempt, the exception makes me think its something to do with my constructor? However I'm really not sure.

```
public static void fill()
{
    try {
        File myFile = new File(filePath);
        Scanner mySc = new Scanner(myFile);

        while (mySc.hasNextLine()) {
            String record = mySc.nextLine();
            String[] parts = record.split(",");

            Student sd = new Student(parts[0], 
                                     Double.parseDouble(parts[1]),
                                     Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));
            group.addNewStudent(vi);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

This is the file content I'm trying to read

```
Harry,1.3,0
Robert,3.5,1
Sally,2.4,0
Damian,3.3,1
```

Comment: Most likely the array property inside `group` is not initialised properly, maybe as an empty array? (you should consider using an ArrayList instead)

Comment: If you used `ex.printStackTrace(System.err);` it would show you on what line the exception was being raised.